# Command not found: py installer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I'm trying to make my Python Tkinter GUI a downloadable .app on MacOs
I installed pyinstaller using pip3 install pyinstaller and when I run it like this:

```
$ pip3 install pyinstaller 
...

$ pyinstaller main.py
```

it return this error:

```
zsh: command not found: pyinstaller
```

I went through many websites and almost all the stack overflow questions about this but I can't find a solution

(I used the default terminal and PyCharm terminal and visualcodestudio terminal but the same result) :(

Comment: you have to add pyinstaller to your $PATH

Comment: im not sure how do I add it to the path?

Comment: did you use `pip` and install it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path

Comment: @cool cloud   I installed it using: pip3 install pyinstaller

Comment: Did you install pyinstaller for your virtual environment(inside pycharm)?

Comment: I tried the samething again with bash in the terminal and pyinstaller worked. the problem i think was with using ZSH as the shell.

Answer (score 1):

In my macbook pro m1 `PyInstaller main.py` worked, but `pyinstaller main.py` doesn't. The issue might be same here!